# How do you get Cruise Control to Email the unit test results from Gallio(MbUnit)?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, mbunit, gallio

I have a build server that uses Cruise Control to run our test cases.  I have successfully configured ccnet 1.4.2 to display the Gallio test results in the webdashboard but I can't seem to get ccservice to email the Gallio test results out in the auto generated Emails.  I have tried editing the .xsl file but to no avail.  I am merging the .xml output from the MsBuild Gallio task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get it to display as you want on the web dashboard then you are close. Now you just need to add the xsl sheet from your dashboard into the xsl folder on the build server and add a refrence to the xsl (just like you did in dashboard.config on the web side) in either the service (ccservice.exe.config) or the console (ccnet.exe.config) config file. And for good housekeeping and to prevent errors later, you should actually include it in both.